# Is there a difference between "moons", "lonely moons" and "vacant moons"?

Tags: starbound

I noticed that some moons are described as

> This moon supports no life and has no atmosphere. However, fuel is abundant here - scans indicate that there is a wealth of it burried below the surface.

others as

> A lonely moon with no breathable atmosphere; the sky is open to the stars, there is fuel below the ground. Likelihood of feeling lonesome and desolate: 92%

and others as

> This vacant moon has no breathable atmosphere, but there are caverns below ground that contain vast fuel deposits. Ins summation: useful, but not exciting.

Is there any difference between the three?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference between the "types" of moons except for the descriptions :P. Sorry.

The navigation console descriptions, from [the offical Starbound wiki](http://starbounder.org/) page [on the moon](http://starbounder.org/Moon), are:

> This moon supports no life and has no atmosphere. However, fuel is abundant here - scans indicate that there is a wealth of it buried below the surface.
>
> This vacant moon has no breathable atmosphere, but there are caverns below ground that contain vast fuel deposits. In summation: useful, but not enticing.
>
> A lonely moon with no breathable atmosphere; the sky is open to the stars, there is fuel below the ground. Likelihood of feeling lonesome and desolate: 92%.

The same thing you said, for you descriptions of the moons, they all, practically, mean the same thing

- There is no atmosphere meaning that the sky is colourless and the moon is void of breathable air, however digging down and blocking off the hole you've dug can create air.
- There's a lot of fuel beneath the ground

The [wiki suggests](http://starbounder.org/Moon) that moons are for the sole purpose of gathering fuel and have nothing else to offer:

> There's only one monster type found on moons; Erchius Ghosts. These monsters are unique to moon biomes.
> They ensure players get in, get their fuel, and quickly exit moons.

Comment: Do you have any source for this?

Comment: Not at all, sorry.

Comment: Just a quick note on terms. There's only one "Wikipedia"; **the** Wikipedia. Sites using similar technology are just called _wikis_.

Comment: @DJ Pirtu will keep in mind next time I refer to a wiki